# How do I access wordpress.com filesystem?

Tags: wordpress.com

All I want to do is be able to start putting PHP in my pages.

So most of the things recommend putting in a plugin by accessing `/wp-content/plugins`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. That's part of the deal working with wordpress.com. You cannot edit the source code. You cannot add JavaScript. You cannot add your own themes. You cannot add arbitrary plug-ins.

If you want to be able to modify WordPress to your liking, you need to download it from wordpress.org and self-host it somewhere.